# How can I send data with a TcpListener, and wait for the response?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have the following code:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
   client.Connect(host, port);

   using (SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), true))
   {
      stream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

      stream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSend));

      int byteRead = 0;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

      do
      {
         byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);
         reponse += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byteRead);
      }
      while (byteRead > 0);
   }
}
```

I send a string to a server, and then wait for the response.

Is this the proper way to do it?

If the server takes some time to process what I sent, will it still work or will stream.Read return 0 and exit the loop? Or if some packets from the response are lost and need to be resent, will it still work?

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned about losing data with a TCP connection, it's up to the network code to assure it will not happen by asking the missing packets again. It is transparent for your application.

Comment: I know I can't lose data, but I was afraid of delayed data. I didn't know Read would block. The MSDN documentation is not really clear. It says:

"This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0."

So I thought that if the server had not yet processed my string, my Read would return 0 and I would never receive anything.

Since Read is a blocking method, it's OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overall structure of your code looks right.

`byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);` will block until all of the response data is retrieved from the server. If the remote server shuts down the connection (timeout, etc), 0 will be returned.

See the remarks [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx).

The framework will properly deal with packets lost during network operations - don't worry about them.

Answer (score -1):

```
public string Method()
{
  m_Client = new TcpClient();
  m_Client.Connect(m_Server, m_Port);
  m_Stream = m_Client.GetStream();
  m_Writer = new StreamWriter(m_Stream);
  m_Reader = new StreamReader(m_Stream);
  m_Writer.WriteLine(request);
  m_Writer.Flush();

  return m_Reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'd give you a -1 for this if I could. Not closing the TcpClient and the NetworkStream retrieved with `m_Client.GetStream()` is just begging for a memory leak. The original poster has coded correctly with `using` statements.

Comment: It's just an example. If you see variable names, I should known that they are class members. To post here, I just joined 2 or more methods. In productions I'm not using above code.